# How can I get base64 to display as a base64 string in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I have been working with an API that uses tokens for authentication.  I am using PHP's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class to login to said API and retrieve the tokens I need to make additional requests..

The problem is that the API should return base64 string tokens, but in PHP, they are not being dealt with as bas64 strings.. I get a string that looks like this:

```
ç$P%’™‹2E‡ºË>Šo_ÑÒúé±N5Tá#=œã
```

Instead of a base64 string that looks like this:

```
ERy/R5ycTG0sbRyH9KeMGpi9kPr6kROyaarFYgsPEOU=
```

> Note: These 2 strings are not actually related, as I could not get php to display the base64 representation of that 1st string.  The base64 string I listed as the 2nd string came from a valid soapUI response.

So I have confirmed with soapUI, that I the tokens do in fact come over as base64 strings, but I cannot get PHP to use them as strings for additional requests.  I have tried doing `base64_decode` and `base64_encode` on the strings, along with a bunch of other encodings/decodings, but none of them have worked so far.

Any ideas as to what is going on here, and how I might be able to use the data the way I need?

Edit: Here is the code I use to get the token data.  It's the DAT api if that helps.

```
$wsdlDat = "http://someurl.com:8000/wsdl/someWSDL.wsdl";
$soapOptions = array( 'loginId' => $userName, 'password' => $userPassword, 'thirdPartyId' => 'KEFKA_TMS', 'trace' => 1 );

$this->datClient = new SoapClient( $wsdlDat , $soapOptions );

$creds = array( 'loginId' => $userName, 'password' => $userPassword, 'thirdPartyId' => 'KEFKA_TMS' );
$loginOptions['loginOperation'] = $creds;

$this->token = $this->datClient->Login($loginOptions);
$this->token = datObjectToArray($this->token);  // TURN STD CLASS OBJ TO ARRAY

$token = $this->token['loginResult']['loginSuccessData']['token']['primary'];
$token2 = $this->token['loginResult']['loginSuccessData']['token']['secondary'];
$exp = $this->token['loginResult']['loginSuccessData']['expiration'];
```

Comment: Can you tell us which API you are using, and show a code sample showing how you get data from it?

Comment: @ErikDolor It's an API that you would have to pay to get access to.  And this is more a question about how to get the base64 string to display as a base64 string.  But if you must know, I will add the code that I use to get the tokens...

Comment: @ErikDolor, Added the code.  It's the DAT api.

Comment: [That API?](http://www.dat.com/products/broker-tms)